# MySQL DB query returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone I'm currently writing a MySQL query that doesn't return anything to the user. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
require_once('MDB2.php');
include "mysql-connect.php"; 

// connect to database

$dsn = "mysql://$username:$password@$host/$dbName"; 
$db =& MDB2::connect($dsn); 
if (PEAR::isError($db)) { 
    die($db->getMessage());
}
$table_name="room";
$db->setFetchMode(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

// list the rooms details

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
$res =& $db->query($sql);
if (PEAR::isError($res)) {
    die($res->getMessage());
}

// display results but if no result has been found then we have to let the user know

if($res->numRows() > 0)
{
    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr align='left'>
    <th scope='col'>Name</th>
    <th scope='col'>Weekend Price</th>
    <th scope='col'>Weekday Price</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = $res->fetchRow());
    {
        echo '<tr align="left">';
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>&pound" . $row['weekend_price'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>&pound" . $row['weekday_price'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "Nothing found.";
}
?>
```

Comment: are you getting errors? enable error reporting

Comment: Is it just my eyes or u r using php4?

Comment: No error reports... but nothing is being returned from the SQL query i.e. the table is empty. I have used the correct field names as well.

Comment: @ItayMoav what's wrong with PHP4?

Comment: Besides the fact it is VERY old, not maintained and who knows what extension version you use, which might be full of bugs...nothing wrong.

Comment: @ItayMoav what can you recommend?

Comment: mysqli (or PDO) and upgrade to php 5.3.8 if you are in production or php 5.4 if you plan to be in development for the next few months. You must test any php4 code thoroughly because the 5.X breaks some backword compatability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon from the end of this line:

```
while($row = $res->fetchRow());
```

It's not entering the contents of the while loop due to that semi-colon.